# Java: How to write a condition for operators?

Tags: java, operators

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJSJX.jpg)
I need some help for an if condition. I know how the basic one works: if x == 1, return something. But how am I supposed to do it, when I need to define certain cases for different operators. Like if the operators is + then the result denoted the sum.

So basically I need to translate the condition in the link into base cases for a recrsive method. We learned that we always use if for basecases. I know how to that with smaller or bigger then, but with operators I don't know.

Comment: **'if the operators is + then the result denoted the sum'** - I don't understand what you mean by this

Comment: An if loop is not a valid control flow structure in Java.

Comment: Please avoid using links for relevant parts of the question. Make the information part of the question (e.g. copy the text). Links die and not everyone can access any url in some environments. There are also other concerns with links.

Answer (score 2):

FYI: `if()` is not a loop `while()` is. `if()` statement works as true or false, if the statement is true then execute a certain code other wise some other code.

For example:

```
if(1==1){// yourcode } // Always as true
// or

String hello="hi there";
if(hello.contains("hi there")){ // Your code which if the statement happen to be true }
    else { // Not true}

int x=3, s=1, i=2;
if(x==(s+i)){ // Your code which if the statement happen to be true }
    else { // Not true}
```

also you can find a lot of tutorials online to help you better understand all the operators!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to state if its positive or negative? If so you would do the following...

```
if(x >= 0){  //this operator is saying if x is greater than or equal to 0 
             // you can remove the equal sign to have it just greater or
             // switch it to less than.

    //if positive


 }else{
      //all other numbers, which would just be negative numbers
 }
```

Comment: I edited the post and added a photo